# How to get names of files?

Tags: php, file, directory

Like, we have folder `/images/`, it has some files inside.

And the script `/scripts/listing.php`

**How can we get names of the all files inside folder `/images/`, in `listing.php`?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Files:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$file\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$file\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

See: [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Answer (score 3):

Even easier than readdir(), use glob:

```
$files = glob('/path/to/files/*');
```

more info on [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 2):

Using either [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/scandir) or [`dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php) makes this problem trivial. To get all files in a directory except the special files `.` and `..` in an array with indices starting from `0`, one can combine `scandir` with `array_diff` and `array_merge`:

```
$files = array_merge(array_diff(scandir($dir), Array('.','..')));
// $files now contains the filenames of every file in the directory $dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using the SPL DirectoryIterator class :

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../images') as $fileInfo) 
{
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just extending on Enrico's post, theres also some checks/modifications you need to do.

```
class Directory
{
    private $path;
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $path = $path;
    }

    public function getFiles($recursive = false,$subpath = false)
    {
        $files = array();
        $path = $subpath ? $subpath : $this->path;

        if(false != ($handle = opendir($path))
        {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
            {
                if($recursive && is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..')
                {
                    array_merge($files,$this->getFiles(true,$file));
                }else
                {
                    $files[] = $path . $file;
                }
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }
}
```

And the usage like so:

```
<?php
$directory = new Directory("/");
$Files = $directory->getFiles(true);
?>
```

This will get you a list like so:

```
/index.php
/includes/functions.php
/includes/.htaccess
//...
```

hoep this helps.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in RecursiveDirectoryIterator / DirectoryIterator...?

Comment: Believe it or not but some people are still using PHP4.x